# Save a PDF File from MySQL to Oracle in C# without any conversion inbetween

Tags: c#, mysql, oracle, pdf, blob

Hi I need to transfer or we can say save PDF which is stored in `BLOB` type from MySQL to Oracle. I know how to do it by converting to it in `byte[]` an then save it in Oracle.

My query is that, is there any other option available to avoid this conversion and speed up the process? Anything like save the MySQL file in a object directly give it to Oracle query?

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether I fully understand your question. Would you like to save the PDF file within the MySQL BLOB in a Java object and then load that object into Oracle using your own Java code, or would you like to avoid to code this altogether and use a utility?

Comment: @gvenzl I want to retrive PDF from ORACLE and save it in to MySQL using C# not in Java.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. But then I did understand you correctly that you would still like to do this in your code, not via any utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just can't escape these passages, if you want to move BLOBs from one RDBMS to another, since your program must:

1. Read binary data from source
2. Write data into destination

If you have **lots** of BLOBs to convert, IMHO a better approach would be:

1. Encapsulate the conversion step in a method
2. Multithread every conversion task according to your system capabilities.

Comment: Yes @Max you got my point but could you please tell me exact method which can convert BLOB and insert into ORACLE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902250/insert-blob-in-oracle-database-with-c-sharp

Comment: What I could suggest you to improve performance by

1) partition your data that you can run program from many nodes
2) rewrite your program into producer-consumer pattern in multi-threads that CPUs help decode/encode vendor specific APIs.
3) make it resumable, so you it is cheaper to stop/restart if anything goes wrong

Answer (score 2):

Oracle and MySQL are disparate systems. When you move binary data from one to other, you have to go through this conversion process.

While both MySql and ODP.Net access Blobs as Stream, in order to read from one and write to another, your program needs to speak the common tongue and that common tongue in .Net is `byte[]`.

Now, with Oracle, you could just store the file as a `BFILE` which is just a filesystem file as opposed to something that is managed by the RDBMS. If you do so, then you could just dump all blobs in MySql in a directory as outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4646912/244353) and you skip the byte array conversion from MySql altogether.

Adding the BFILE to Oracle will then be a batch job that you can run once the MySql dump is completed:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY test_dir AS '/tmp'  -- replace tmp with actual my sql dump directory 

-- Inserting the BFiles
INSERT INTO my_bfile_table VALUES (..., bfilename(test_dir, 'file1.pdf'));
INSERT INTO my_bfile_table VALUES (..., bfilename(test_dir, 'file2.pdf'));
...
```

Note that ODP.Net [doesn't let you update](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featLOBsupp.htm#CIHGHGDE) `BFILE`s, so you have to insert them via SQL Commands as shown above. You can do it via [JDBC and other interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_bfile_ops.htm#g1074815) though.

If the files are large, you could actually gain some performance improvements due to [reduced transaction log activity](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5671517437591#9150057816208). There are off course some trade-offs associated with storing as `BFILE` (like reduced manageability, need to separately backup filesystem etc.), so you may need to consider those.

If you have the option, then explore this idea - skip storing the PDFs in database altogether (BLOB or BFILE), move them to a CDN and store just a locator (URI) to the CDN asset in your database. Not only will the database be relieved largely, the end user experience will likely improve as well. It depends on your application and its requirements of course, but it may be worth exploring.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not another option *(storing in byte[])* while reading BLOBs from MySql. But if you have a lot of records to move, while inserting Oracle, you can use **Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy** in **ODP.NET** for performance consideration.

http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm

Comment: OracleBulkCopy is best suited when importing data to empty table. If destination table already has records, then [primary/unique indexes can be put in unusable state](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/3754) (workaround - [recreate or rebuild these indexes](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01502_index_string_string_or_partition_of_such_index_is_in_usable_state.htm)).

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you have a PDF file in MySQL database which you want to move to Oracle DB keeping the datatype as BLOB.

The first thing you need to do is, move the file to a directory location from where Oracle can read it. and then all you need to do is load the PDF into a BLOB column of your table.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Load_lob 
AS 
  id        NUMBER; 
  pdf1      BLOB; 
  locator   BFILE; 
  bfile_len NUMBER; 
  bf_desc   VARCHAR2(30); 
  bf_name   VARCHAR2(30); 
  bf_dir    VARCHAR2(30); 
  bf_typ    VARCHAR2(4); 
  ctr       INTEGER; 
  CURSOR get_id IS 
    SELECT bfile_id, 
           bfile_desc, 
           bfile_type 
    FROM   pdf_table; 
BEGIN 
    OPEN get_id; 

    LOOP 
        FETCH get_id INTO id, bf_desc, bf_typ; 

        EXIT WHEN get_id%NOTFOUND; 

        dbms_output.Put_line('ID: ' 
                             ||To_char(id)); 

        SELECT bfile_loc 
        INTO   locator 
        FROM   pdf_table 
        WHERE  bfile_id = id; 

        dbms_lob.Filegetname(locator, bf_dir, bf_name); 

        dbms_output.Put_line('Dir: ' 
                             ||bf_dir); 

        dbms_lob.Fileopen(locator, dbms_lob.file_readonly); 

        bfile_len := dbms_lob.Getlength(locator); 

        dbms_output.Put_line('ID: ' 
                             ||To_char(id) 
                             ||' length: ' 
                             ||To_char(bfile_len)); 

        SELECT temp_blob 
        INTO   pdf1 
        FROM   temp_blob; 

        bfile_len := dbms_lob.Getlength(locator); 

        dbms_lob.Loadfromfile(pdf1, locator, bfile_len, 1, 1); 

        INSERT INTO internal_graphics 
        VALUES      (id, 
                     bf_desc, 
                     pdf1, 
                     bf_typ); 

        dbms_output.Put_line(bf_desc 
                             ||' Length: ' 
                             ||To_char(bfile_len) 
                             || ' Name: ' 
                             ||bf_name 
                             ||' Dir: ' 
                             ||bf_dir 
                             ||' ' 
                             ||bf_typ); 

        dbms_lob.Fileclose(locator); 
    END LOOP; 
END; 

/
```